# alignment of textbox and image button(asp.net)

Tags: css, asp.net, alignment

here is my output of my UI
[image]

may I make the Date textbox and the image button align straight like the task name dropdown and the add image button??

here is my code for asp.net

```
<table id="fix">
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="Label" style="width:80px;"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px" Style="width: 150px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="USERNAME" DataValueField="USERNAME" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT USERNAME FROM USERMASTER WHERE USERSTATUS = 1 AND USERACCESSRIGHTS = 'Non-Administrator' ORDER BY USERNAME"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="text" size="10" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox> 
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Image/calandar.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click"/><br />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTask" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 200px">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Width="150" Style="width: 150px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="TASKNAME" DataValueField="TASKNAME">
                                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CssClass="imagebutton" ImageUrl="~/Image/add-icon.png" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" Style="position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 20px;" />
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT TASKNAME FROM TASKMASTER WHERE TASKSTATUS='1'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

Your comment and suggestion are much appreaciated! Thanks

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for the same, so that we can help you.

Comment: try `<td valign="middle">`

Comment: @stanze thank! https://jsfiddle.net/tj2g3Lf6/

Comment: @Elyor I cant find the atrribute of valign in my <td>

Comment: How about adding same css code from the task image to the calendar one?